# How to get the JSON response in a specific format?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to test a Module and I need to recreate a json as follows:

```
$billing_info['billing']->customer_id
$billing_info['billing']['source']->exp_year
```

I tried to recreate it as follows:

```
$arr = json_encode(['id'=>'card_17LHmCI49Oxjrr81SringkGq', 'exp_year'=>2018, 'exp_month' => 07, 'funding' => 'credit', 'brand' => 'Visa', 'last4' => '4242']);

$customer = json_encode(['customer_id' => 'cus_7aSheljul3mkAB', 'source' =>json_decode($arr)]);
```

But I'm not able to call `dd($billing_info['billing']->customer_id);`

The desired JSON response is like as follows:

```
[
  "billing" => [
    {"customer_id": 12 }
    "source" => {
      "exp_year": 2018
      "exp_month": 7
      "funding": "credit"
      "brand": "Visa"
      "last4": "4242"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Tag with the language you're using.

Comment: the two code blocks have no relation to each whatsoever(variable names, keys in the array). Besides json_encode is not necessary, as that putputs a string

Comment: You are trying to use `$billing_info['billing']` as object(`->customer_id`) and as array(`['source']`) in a same time. It is possible in php objects(magic `offsetGet`). But I'm afraid, you are not able to recreate such behavior in json.

Comment: @bpoiss you wanna check this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$customer = new stdClass();
$customer->customer_id=1;
$customer->source=new stdClass();
$customer->source->exp_year=2018;
$billing_info = array('billing'=>$customer);
```

update1:

Just realized that what you want is impossible:

```
$billing_info['billing']->customer_id
$billing_info['billing']['source']->exp_year
```

In the 1st line you assume $billing_info['billing'] is an object, while in the 2nd line you assume it's an array. Please decide which one you prefer:

```
$billing_info['billing']->customer_id
$billing_info['billing']->source->exp_year

$billing_info['billing']['customer_id']
$billing_info['billing']['source']->exp_year
```

Optionally ['exp_year'] is also possible

update2:

Please include a VALID json! You can check it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: `dd($billing_info['billing']->customer_id);` this is not accessible.

Comment: So I've to create a new class for this?

Comment: here these work: var_dump($billing_info); print_r($billing_info['billing']->customer_id); I don't know what is dd()

Comment: `dd()` is die and dump()

Comment: I can access `dd($billing_info['billing']->customer_id);` but just not the `dd($billing_info['billing']['source']->exp_year);` But it's accessible with the syntax `dd($billing_info['billing']->source->exp_year);`

Comment: I saw the update. What I'm trying to recreate is a JSON response from Stripe. So I'm getting the response from them just like how I wanted to recreate.

Comment: I believe, Stackoverflow is a place for sharing and caring. You don't have to be so mean to somebody who is just trying to learn things. You might be a master of everything. That doesn't mean you should treat others like stupids. Thanks for your efforts, but I don't think you are helping me.